# Kafka Consumers get many replays when new consumers connect

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I'm playing with Kafka, trying to get to grips with it. One of the things we need to be able to do is run load-balanced sets of servers - for redundancy/high availability/etc - and have then get rebooted independently of each other. Should be simple.

What I've found though is slightly strange. If I'm running a single Kafka consumer that is processing a set of messages, and then I add a second consumer *to the same consumer group* whilst the messages are being processed, I get the entire set of messages many times instead of just once.

For example, here are my log files from just such a run: https://gist.github.com/sazzer/5604d0652ff14533654c8b543942c10e

This is using 2 Topics - kafka-live and kafka-bulk. Each topic has 2 Partitions - one for each consumer. The test is then adding 20 messages to the bulk queue followed by 10 to the live queue. (That was actually testing something else but I just re-used the setup)

From the logs you'll see that each message gets processed a total of 3 times, instead of just once as I'd expected.

The code for this is as follows: https://gist.github.com/sazzer/c67e4db9a04aac8c0d46bbc21188775d

This is using Spring Boot and Spring Kafka, and - apart from this one case - it's just worked.

Am I missing something to stop it replaying all the messages when a new consumer turns up? Or is this just something I have to deal with?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT` to `false`.

Instead of relying on the client to do commits, the listener container will commit the offsets after each BATCH of records after they have all been processed; it will also commit any pending offsets when a rebalance occurs; you can also set the `AckMode` to `RECORD` and it will commit the offset for each record is processed.

You can also manually assign the partitions to instances and don't use group management for assignment.